# How to get attachments for a specific post type?

Tags: attachments, post-type

[I have this page where I am showing all post's attachments.](http://www.101greatgoals.com/picture-gallery/)

This is the code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' =>25,
    'post_parent' => null, // Post-> ID;
    'numberposts' => null,
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);

$post_count = count ($attachments);

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo "<div class=\"post photo col3\">";
        $url = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);// extraigo la _posturl del attachmnet      
        $img = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
        $title = get_the_title($attachment->post_parent);//extraigo titulo
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'"><img title="'.$title.'" src="'.$img.'"></a>';
        echo "</div>";
    }   
}
?>
```

Now, I have the 'post', 'page' and 'videos' post_types.
I am getting all of them but I want to display 'post' post_type only.
How do I exclude 'video' post_type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

     foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

         $attachments = get_children( array (
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_per_page'  => 25
        ), ARRAY_A );


      if( $attachments ) {
         //continue with what you were doing

      }
   }
```

Comment: Not working for me... It's giving me a sever error while it's working normally if I undo the change.

Comment: You were probably missing the closing `}` from the foreach loop.  I updated the sample code to include it.

Answer (score 0):

just paste the following code anywhere in your post file and attachments will be displayed.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => null,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
        the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
    }
}
```